# How do I consolidate entries from multiple employee blogs into a single RSS feed

Tags: sharepoint, rss

Our current SharePoint environment has Mysites setup as separate site collections where users create their blogs. It is a real challenge to know these blogs indivdually and I usually grab the RSS feed the first time I visit and then susbcribe from within Outlook. To help out non-techies, we'd like to be able to consolidate the entries from some top (regular) bloggers on our portal into a single feed that can then be used to subscribe from Outlook or display on a page on the portal.

Any ideas on how to go about this would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time and have a great day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consolidate these top feeds into an [OPML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML) file. Here's a [great example](http://www.scripting.com/feeds/top100.opml). [Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA012299401033.aspx) 2007 can parse this and add it as a a collection of feeds.

You could also write a quick web part to parse the OPML file and download the top *n* posts from each feed. Sahil Malik has already done this hard work and you could use his [examples](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006-7-Sharepoint_Webparts_AS_-_Writing_the_WebParts_-_The_OPMLEditor_WebPart.aspx) as a jump off.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit - this will not work if your feeds are not publicly available.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

> About Pipes
>
> Pipes is a powerful composition tool
>   to aggregate, manipulate, and mashup
>   content from around the web.
>
> Like Unix pipes, simple commands can
>   be combined together to create output
>   that meets your needs:
>
> ```
> * combine many feeds into one, then sort, filter and translate it.
> * geocode your favorite feeds and browse the items on an interactive
> ```
>
> map.
>       * power widgets/badges on your web site.
>       * grab the output of any Pipes as RSS, JSON, KML, and other formats.

Comment: I love Pipes, but this assumes that his data is accessible outside his firewall.

Comment: The data is certainly behind a firewall. Pipes won't work fr this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no fan of PHP and obviously you are using some MS products but here is a PHP script that does it.

http://www.feedforall.com/rssmesh.htm

Perhaps you can use this as a basis for an asp/ asp.net page that will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to release a file to your _layouts directory, coding it to spit an RSS feed to the user. Maybe use a query string to decide which RSS feeds to read from.

Maybe start with [Eric Shupp's](http://sharingpoint.blogspot.com/2007/05/sharepoint-2007-rss-aggregator-web-part.html) webpart and progress from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into open-source self-hosted stuff you can try python-based webapp called [Planet](http://www.planetplanet.org/). It has RSS and html output (with template support).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our solution here:
[Anatomy of an Employee Blogging Solution](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/archive/2008/11/16/anatomy-of-a-sharepoint-solution-blogs-home-screenshots.aspx)

I talk about just how we achieved it. We are also very close to releasing this as a solution, so feel free to drop me an email (daniel@zevenseas.com) if you are interested. Or try our demo: http://demo.zevenseas.com

Comment: looking forward to seeing this!

I own blogs for SharePoint vNext, let me know if you have feedback

Comment: You can take a look now http://demo.zevenseas.com drop me an email and daniel@zevenseas.com if you want to get a login.